# How to make datetime.now function update when put within a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a for Loop that repeats the piece of code 100 times, the problem is that the datetime import won't update within the loop.

Code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print("%02d-%02d-%04d") % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
#below is the loop
for i in range(0, 100):
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("%02d:%02d:%02d") % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

all it outputs is the same hours, minutes and seconds as when I first pressed run.

```
Output below:

11:59:0711:59:07

11:59:0711:59:07
```

(This carries on for 100 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `now` again:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
  time.sleep(1)
  now = datetime.now()
  print ("%02d:%02d:%02d") % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

`now` is an object, it doesn't get the new time when you use it (it would be terrible).

Comment: you need to make it `now = datetime.now()` otherwise you'll get an attribute error when you use `now.hour`

Comment: Yes, I know, someone made an edit to remove the call!

Comment: No, I made an edit to *add* them. You left them off originally, then subsequently overwrote my edit with a previous version which still didn't have them.

Answer (score 0):

you are only sampling `now` one time, you need to do it inside the for loop like so

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print("%02d-%02d-%04d") % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
#below is the loop
for i in range(0, 100):
  time.sleep(1)
  now = datetime.now()
  print ("%02d:%02d:%02d") % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the now = datetime.now() within the loop?

```
for i in range(0,100):
    time.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.now()
    print ("%02d:%02d:%02d") % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```